# How do I get a nested collection correctly using GraphQL?

Tags: symfony, graphql, api-platform.com

I have 2 entities:

```
User
Book
```

Both entities are exposed as API resources (I am using DTO)

```
//src/Entity/User.php
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
    'get' => [
        'security' => 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")'
    ],
],
    graphql: [
    'collection_query' => [
        'security' => 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")'
    ],
    'item_query',
],
    itemOperations: [
    'get',
],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:write']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read']],
    output: UserOutput::class
)]
...

//src/Entity/Book.php
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
    'get' => [
        'security' => 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")'
    ],
],
    graphql: [
    'collection_query' => [
        'security' => 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")'
    ],
    'item_query',
],
    itemOperations: [
    'get',
],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['book:write']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['book:read']],
    output: BookOutput::class
)]
...
```

I want to allow only admins to view the collections of both entities, but I also need to be able to get the nested collection:

```
query {
    user(id: "/api/users/01F63NKKN7DWYB74K6G5N33DPP") {
    id
    books{
      edges{
        node{
          id
        }
      }
    }
    }
}

Result: Access Denied.
```

I can get a collection using REST, but how do I get a collection using GraphQL? I'm confused. What can I do in this situation?

UPD:

```
//src/Dto/UserOutput.php
final class UserOutput
{
    #[Groups(['user:read', 'book:read'])]
    public Ulid $id;

    ...

    /** @var Book[] */
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    public iterable $books;
}

//src/Dto/BookOutput.php
final class BookOutput
{
    #[Groups(['book:read', 'user:read'])]
    public Ulid $id;

    #[Groups(['book:read'])]
    public User $user;

    ...
}
```

Comment: does it work if security is disabled/commented out?

Comment: @xadm Yes of course